# Need to bind the click events using Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I am new in Angular JS. I have written a script that open a modal box. There are few buttons in that modal box on which I want to apply the click event.

Below I have mentioned my code:

```
angular.module("vss_shoppingcart_modal",["ui.bootstrap","dialogs","ngSanitize"]).controller("vss_shoppingcart_dialogService",function($scope,$dialogs,$sce){

  $scope.init = function(){
    dlg = $dialogs.create("/dialogs/whatsyourname.html","vssShoppingCartCTRL",{},{key: false,back: "static"});
  };

}) // end dialogsServiceTest
.controller("vssShoppingCartCTRL",function($scope,$sce,$http,$modalInstance,data){
  $http({
       method: "GET",
       url: "' . $url . '"
   }).
   success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.trustedHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml(data); // Apply the html to modal
   });

$scope.cancel = function(){
                $modalInstance.dismiss("canceled");  
            }; // end cancel

  $scope.removeProduct = function(event){
    $http({
           method: "GET",
           url: event.target.id
       }).
       success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

       }).
       error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            // or server returns response with an error status.
       });
  }; // End removeProduct

  $scope.updateQuantity = function(event){
    $http({
           method: "POST",
           url: "' . $this->getUrl('shoppingcartpopup/index/updateCart') . '",
           data: { "product_id": event.target.id, "qty": "2", "update_cart_action":"update_qty"}
       }).
       success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
           $http({
               method: "GET",
               url: "' . $url . '"
           }).
           success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
               $scope.trustedHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml(data);
           });
       }).
       error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            // or server returns response with an error status.
       });
  }; // End updateQuantity

}) // end whatsYourNameCtrl
.run(["$templateCache",function($templateCache){
  $templateCache.put("/dialogs/whatsyourname.html","<div class='ngModal' ng-bind-html='trustedHtml'></div>");
}]);// end run / module
```

On page load, I have passed a static block to modal window then by ajax request, I have updated the content again.

I don't know how to apply ng-click event on  button in my view file.

In view, I have a link button -

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dialog-titlebar-close" role="button" ng-bind="cancel()" ng-click="cancel()">
    <span class="header_close_icon">close</span>
</a>
```

ng-click is not working on this link.

Comment: Why are you using `ng-bind="cancel()"`?

Comment: ng-bind is used with Angular JS for click event same as in Javascript.

Comment: The `ngBind` attribute tells Angular to replace the text content of the specified HTML element with the value of a given expression, and to update the text content when the value of that expression changes. Read [Docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind)

Comment: Oh Sorry. Do you have any idea about how to bind the events in my example

Comment: `ng-click="cancel()"` is perfect way of achieving what you want. why its not working thats the issue

Comment: At the time of page loading, I have append the code in modal box as mentioned in code -$http({ method: "GET", url: "' . $url . '" }). success(function(data, status, headers, config) { $scope.trustedHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml(data); // Apply the html to modal }). Becuase of this ng-click event doesn't bind with link. I think, this is the same problem occurs with jQuery but I am not able to find any solution of it in Angular.

Comment: Hi Guys, I am still in the same problem.